# how to read the header txt by procedure in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

when executing a procedure to read a file the system ignores the first line, how do I solve it?

Comment: All I can say is that I can't debug code I don't see.

Answer (score 0):

You are a little scant on details, but options:

1) If you are using external tables, use the SKIP clause

2) If you are using SQL Load, use the SKIP clause

3) If you are using APEX, tick the "Has Headers" box on upload

4) If you are using UTL_FILE then do UTL_FILE.GET_LINE to get the first line and discard.

5) If you are reading a CLOB, look for chr(10) and/or chr(13) to find the end of the first line using DBMS_LOB.INSTR

We can't provide much more than that because your question is so vague ...

Comment: I use option 4, I need to import the first line

Comment: GET_LINE looks for the standard end-of-line character(s) for the platform. If it is going further than than, or not far enough, look in the file to see if there are some spurious characters.  Or if the file was created on Windows and being read on Unix or vice-versa